# Jquery edit style atrribute within tree <ins> tag within anchor

Tags: jquery

I am trying to alter the ins tag style attribute on html which looks like this

```
<ul>
  <li class="pad">
    <a>
     <ins style="margin-left: 5px"></ins>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="no_pad">
    <a>
      <ins style="margin-left: 0px"></ins>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="pad">
    <a>
      <ins style="margin-left: 5px"></ins>
    </a>
  </li>
<ul>
```

I only want to grab the list elements with the "pad" class tag. How can I grab all the list elements and then get down to the ins tag to edit the style attribute on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple CSS selector:

```
$('li.pad ins').css('cssPropertyName', 'CssPropertyValue');
```

This will add the `cssPropertyName` property, and set its value to the supplied `cssPropertyValue`.

If you'd rather, albeit unnecessarily, use the `attr()` method:

```
$('li.pad ins').attr('style', function(i, v) {
    return v + 'cssPropertyName: cssPropertyValue;'
});
```

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, isn't it just what you are looking for? Or i misunderstood you

```
$('li.pad ins').css('margin-left','20px');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
$('li.pad > a > ins').css({
    'color':'red',
    'font-weight':'bold'
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/oforex/1/edit).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `class`, `id`, `attr` or `tags` as jQuery selectors, this case `ins` is a tag, so you can find it by the following.

```
$('li.pad').find('ins');
```